# Unable to open remote audio file via AVPlayer, even though the link seems to be correct

Tags: ios, audio, streaming, avfoundation, core-audio

I'm trying to build a simple streaming application, and right now I'm feeding a direct link to a file (for example [this one](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/43847830/acoustic.mp3)) to AVPlayer, using this simple code snippet:

```
_player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:@"(file url here)"]];

[_player play];
```

However, it played nothing, so I tried 3rd-party components like The Amazing Audio Engine, and I got the following error:

```
AEAudioFileLoaderOperation.m:121: ExtAudioFileOpenURL result -43
```

As far as I understand, it cannot open a file via provided url. However, I tried opening the very same url in a browser, and it works perfectly (even on a device).

Where should I look for a source of this error? Also are there any alternatives to playing/serving an mp3 file for streaming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please disregard this question, I just realized that I had a silent mode turned on and actually everything worked just fine. In my defence, I should say that rocking volume buttons don't make any change, and you have to somehow turn off the silent mode in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Try `AVAudioPlayer`. If your project has ARC enabled, then the player should not be declared as a local variable.  It should be declared as a property.  Otherwise, ARC will deallocate the player before it has a chance to play.

Comment: Ah, my bad, I do use it as a property, I'll change the code above

Comment: However, from what I've read, AVAudioPlayer should not be used for remote files, thus the AVPlayer

Comment: Oops, you are absolutely correct. I've only used it with files. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1634/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

From Apple documentation: To create NSURL objects for file system paths, use fileURLWithPath:isDirectory: instead